# Orchard NHibernate Session Factory Initialize

Tags: autofac, orchardcms

I'm currently looking at the Orchard source code and can't find where the NHibernate Session Factory been registered into the AutoFac. Anybody can help with that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is `ShellContainerFactory`.

In `ShellContainerFactory`, it will scan all from `IDependency` inherited classes and register them. The `SessionFactoryHolder` is inherited from `IDependency` so it will be registered automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard.Framework\Data\SessionFactoryHolder.cs is probably a good place to start. I believe that's where the NHib configuration is built and the session is initialized.

Comment: Thank you for reply. That's what I checked and still have no any idea how it has been registered into autofac.

Comment: It implements ISingletonDependency, a marker interface used for dependency resolution. does that help?